# Requiring test files with webpack for use with mocha or similar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, webpack, mocha.js

I'm trying to use webpack to bundle tests into a pack that I can pass directly to mocha. My webpack config looks something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ...,

  output: ...,

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?(.erb)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: [
            'react',
            [ 'latest', { 'es2015': { 'modules': false } } ]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [],

  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.js', '.jsx' ],
    modules: [
      path.resolve('../app/javascript'),
      path.resolve('../vendor/node_modules')
    ]
  },

  resolveLoader: {
    modules: [ path.resolve('../vendor/node_modules') ]
  }
}
```

(From https://github.com/rails/webpacker)

My entry point looks like this, which I've seen references to elsewhere:

```
var context = require.context('../path/to/tests', true, /.+\.test\.js?$/);
context.keys().forEach(context);
module.exports = context;
```

Now this works, and produces a bundle, say tests.js, that I can pass to mocha:

```
$ mocha tests.js
```

However, this makes webpack recompile all test files every time something is changed, which is really slow. For my application code, where I import modules using regular import statements, webpack only recompiles files that have changed.

Changing my entry point to something like:

```
require('../path/to/tests/foo.test.js');
require('../path/to/tests/bar.test.js');
require('../path/to/tests/baz.test.js');
...
```

Seems to have the desired effect, but there are hundreds of test files, and it seems cumbersome to have to manually import or require each one.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack is recompiling your tests because you are using `require.context`. The docs for using it are [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html). Normally when running a series of tests with mocha you can just use `mocha ../path/**.test.js` to run all of them. This, of course, won't work if you are using new features from js which are not supported by Node.

One way to get around this is to pass compiler options to mocha, and it will use babel under the hood. A more detailed explanation can be found on [this blog post](http://jamesknelson.com/testing-in-es6-with-mocha-and-babel-6/). The general idea is to run mocha with `--compilers js:babel-core/register` which finds your `.babelrc` file.

If you are on a mac or linux, you can use the following command to make writing a bash expression to find all of your tests a little easier.

`find ./path -name '*.test.js' | xargs mocha`